# How to adjust smart guidelines to show distance between 2 objects and other things?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Let's say I have this button in Illustrator CC 2017 (on mac).

How do I adjust my smart guidelines to pop up the pixel distance between the text and end of button?

[image]

Another scenario, I have these 2 squares. How do I find the distance (in pixels) between these 2 shapes? I know in Sketch, you can measure the distance by selecting 1 object, press 'option' key, and hover over another to find the distance. How can I do this in Illustrator?

[image]

Update: About the function in sketch, Sketch has great tooltips that measures the distance between objects with their tooltips (view image below). How can I get a similar function in Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: so you don't want to use the measure tool?

Comment: Can't do it with Smart Guides. Not Possible. Use the Ruler Tool.

Comment: @JohnBurgess the measure tool shows you in a infobox, but is there a faster way of finding the distance?

Comment: Illustrator doesn't have any tools natively for this. You'd have to search for a plug in if anything.